# python string ' " ' : single double quote inside string

Tags: python, command-line

A double quote looks like this ".  If I put this inside a python string I get this `' " '`.  In python, I can put two double quotes in a string `' "" '` and this gets printed as two double quotes.  However, I cannot put a single double quote in a string, as before, `' " '`.  I am doing this in eclipse with pydev and it gives an `error: "encountered "\r" (13), after : ""`.  I am trying to do the following with command pipe and file names:

```
logA = 'thing.txt'
cmdpipe = os.popen('copy "C:\upe\' + logA + '"' + ' "C:\upe\log.txt"')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes, otherwise it will do odd things.

```
logA = 'thing.txt'
cmdpipe = os.popen(
    'copy "C:\\upe\\' + logA + '"' + ' "C:\\upe\\log.txt"')
```

Edit: A more pythonic way would be this though:

```
logA = 'thing.txt'
cmdpipe = os.popen('copy "C:\\upe\\{}" "C:\\upe\\log.txt"'.format(logA))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the backslashes:

```
logA = 'thing.txt'
cmdpipe = os.popen('copy "C:\\upe\\' + logA + '"' + ' "C:\\upe\\log.txt"')
```

Typically, one would use raw strings (`r'...'`) when there are backslashes inside a string literal. However, as pointed out by @BrenBarn, this won't work in this case.

Comment: A raw string still will not work, since even in a raw string the backslash still escapes the quote character at the end.  You can't have a raw string with an odd number of trailing backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash after `upe` is escaping the first single quote closing:

```
'copy "C:\upe\' + logA + '"' + ' "C:\upe\log.txt"'
--------------^ add an escape at least here, and it will work!
```

Another option is to compose your command in more steps:

```
basepath = r'C:\upe'
inpath = os.path.join(basepath, logA)
outpath = os.path.join(basepath, 'log.txt')
logA = 'thing.txt'
command = 'copy "%s" "%s"' % (inpath, outpath)

print command

cmdpipe = os.popen(command)
```