# Right speech mark placement for Python code

Tags: python

I have written this piece of code where you can input the amount of chocolate needed in a recipe and it will return the amount in 5kg and 1kg pieces. What is wrong which this piece of code? I have got integers for the variables but it shows a syntax error!

```
kg = int(input("How much chocolate do you need?"))
fivekgs = kg // 5
onekgs = kg % 5
print ("You will need,"fivekgs" 5kg blocks and, "onekgs" 1kg blocks!")
```

Have i got the speech mark placements wrong or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python string ' " ' : single double quote inside string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651779/python-string-single-double-quote-inside-string)

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting you get here (and hopefully in your editor). The colour change for `fivekgs` and `onekgs` is a clear indication that something weird is happening inside your string.

Comment: With the updated code it's clear that you're trying to interpolate variables, not nest quotes. See [Is there a Python equivalent to Ruby's string interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4450592/354577) and [Python's many ways of string formatting — are the older ones (going to be) deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13451989/354577) instead.

Comment: It looks like you want this:
`"You will need, '{}' 5kg blocks and, '{}' 1kg blocks!".format(fivegs, onekgs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(f'You will need,{fivekgs} 5kg blocks and, {onekgs} 1kg blocks!')
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to:

`print("You will need, 'fivekgs' 5kg blocks and, 'onekgs' 1kg blocks!")`

Or:

`print('You will need, "fivekgs" 5kg blocks and, "onekgs" 1kg blocks!')`

Comment: With more code it's clear that OP is trying to _interpolate_, not quote strings.